# Getting error TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get data from a server and show that data on a webpage or console for that i need to authenticate that server but i am getting a error at

```
resp.send(JSON.stringify(body));
     ^
```

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

That server is some already there which gives data when  we hit it so i am getting data from it
Thanks in advance

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var mysql=require("mysql");
var request = require('request');
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser   =   require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



  app.get('/service',function(req,res){
    var id = req.query.name; 
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(id);
    request.post({

                 url    : 'http://example.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/'+id,
                 json   : {
                             userName:'username',
                             password:'password'
                           }
                },
                function(error, resp, body){
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        resp.send(JSON.stringify(body));
                    }
            });



  });
console.log('running');
app.listen(8082);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this guy keeps deleting and reopening the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering anyway, maybe he stops then...

Please read through your code more carefully before posting a question on Stackoverflow over and over again. You're using `resp.send(...)` instead of `res.send(...)`.

`resp` is the response of your server-side API call, `res` is the response-object of the client request. You probably want to send your response there..

Comment: Thank you its working sorry for inconvenience as no one answered i thought reposting helps

Comment: @RohitRock: Resposting and deleting questions is a good way to get your account question-banned...

Comment: How to implement or execute a                                                                                   curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2/issue/MKY-1    command using nodejs